# Why does one system take so much more time to "apply personal settings" when it boots?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp

The story is that I have one server (Windows 2003 server) and 10 systems with XP Professional. I have a local area connection to connect them all. I also have DNS on the server and systems logon on DNS account.

My issue is that I start the server first and then all the systems. All the other systems start within 1-2 minutes but one system is taking more time after logon. It shows "Loading your personal settings" and takes more time then the others. After then it works fine, no more issues.

My question is that how I can reduce this time. I have Googled but not found a sufficient solution.

This question may be a duplicate of another question but I did not got a resolving answer for this issue.

Comment: Users don't logon to DNS. You've made this mistake in several questions. You really need to make an effort to learn what the various server systems do if you expect anyone to take you seriously. Anybody who properly qualifies to participate on this site is expected to have a basic understanding of things like DNS and user authentication. More importantly, they are expected to know that there is no connection between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Is the user being logged on the SAME? If not then the user being logged on has a very large Windows profile, probably in the order of hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: This includes things the user has saved to desktop, doesn't it?

Comment: same user doesn't take more time to another system but different user take same time on same system

Comment: Could try running procmon from sysinternals and have it monitor the boot up and logon processes and see if something is holding it up.